# How to change code to format citation?

Tags: citing, changes

I have used a template from overleaf in which citations output is shown below

> or thepresident.3No clear understanding has emerged about the context
> in which scandals involving legislators are most likely to occur,
> however—both **peters80** and **welch97**

and the code in the class file is

{

```
\newif\if@usebibtex \@usebibtexfalse
\DeclareOption{bibtex}{\@usebibtextrue}

    \if@usebibtex
    \RequirePackage{natbib}
    \else
    \PassOptionsToPackage{natbib=true}{biblatex}
    \RequirePackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
    \fi
```

}

How to modify the code to have output like

> Authors and dates do not have to be written out after the first
> reference; use the bracketed number. Also, it is not necessary to
> write “in reference **[2].**” Just write “in **[2].**”.

I would be grateful if someone could explain the code

Comment: What class are you using? Also, `peters80` looks like the biber/bibtex step was not run, just the first latex step. The compilation sequence is usually: latex, biber, latex. I presume bibtex would work the same way, as second step, since the information has to get from the bib file into the tex document.

Answer (score 0):

[Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/237192) Usually it is a good idea to post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/237192) on this site. This time I did that for you:) this means I had to guess which packages you use.

```
\documentclass{article}
% The following will create/overwrite a file named "mybibfile.tex". Just used as an example.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybibfile.tex}
   @article{einstein,
      author =       "Albert Einstein",
      title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
      [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
      journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
      volume =       "322",
      number =       "10",
      pages =        "891--921",
      year =         "1905",
      DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
   }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex} % <<====== HERE IS WHAT YOU WANT TO CHANGE! You want to change the style from former "authoryear" to e.g. "numeric". See e.g. https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibtex_bibliography_styles for more styles.
\addbibresource{mybibfile.tex} % <-- Here we say that out bibliography content is in "mybibfile.tex".

\begin{document}
   This is a very important sentence, thats why I cite it (see \cite{einstein}).
   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Most things are explained inline, that's why I don't have to add much. I think this is the normal way to achieve a numeric citation style.

What the code in your class file means is the following (as far as I can understand it):

- check wether `bibtex` is used
- if yes, then force the author to load `natbib`
- if no, then add the option `natbib=true` to `biblatex` and force the author to use `biblatex-chicago` with options `authordate,backend=biber`.
  The last bullet point is why I think won't be allowed to change the style to `numeric` (or similar).

Please see that I used `biblatex` instead of `biblatex-chicago` as I don't have the latter installed. This is maybe not the most helpful answer to your question, but I hope I can help you at least a bit.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am trying to make modifications in the class file and the solution you provided in not for a class file I suppose. I have edited the code adding two more lines. Although some concepts are clear through your answer.